# Error related to OneToMany and getting data using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, one-to-many

As you can see, I have two classes, `Person` and `Item`, as well as their corresponding tables in the database, in the `App` class, I am trying to get all the things of a person using a one-to-many relationship using Hibernate.

**Person**

```java
package org.example.model;


import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Item> items;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Item**

```java
package org.example.model;


import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "item_name")
    String itemName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person owner;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", itemName='" + itemName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**App**

```java
package org.example;


import org.example.model.Item;
import org.example.model.Person;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.time.Period;
import java.util.List;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .addAnnotatedClass(Period.class).addAnnotatedClass(Item.class);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        try {

            session.beginTransaction();

            Person person = session.get(Person.class, 1);
            System.out.println(person);

            List<Item> items = person.getItems();
            System.out.println(items);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Association 'org.example.model.Item.owner' targets an unknown entity named 'org.example.model.Person'
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1879)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1826)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1733)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:735)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:773)
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:23)
```

1. I tried to change different versions of dependencies in pom.xml as well as the java version and rebuilt the project.
2. Tried to re-prescribe classes.
3. I checked the DB connection (it is there because it eats the transition to the columns I need by their names in the `@Column` annotation).

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in the attached Person class. You attached an App class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).